# What is this line trying to do?

Tags: c++, struct, casting, function-pointers

I'm trying to compile a [triangle++](http://compgeom.com/~piyush/scripts/triangle/) library (a c++ wrapper over Triangle.h library) and i am stuck at this line:

```
else if (m->lastflip->prevflip == (struct flipstacker *) &insertvertex)
```

which obviously throws a type cast error (VC++12):

```
cannot convert from 'piyush::insertvertexresult (__thiscall piyush::* )(piyush::mesh *,piyush::behavior *,piyush::vertex,piyush::otri *,piyush::osub *,int,int)' to 'piyush::flipstacker *'
```

Casting a function pointer to a struct pointer? This is some **dark magic** I don't know about.

Here is the `insertvertex` function:

```
enum insertvertexresult insertvertex(struct mesh *m, struct behavior *b,
                                     vertex newvertex, struct otri *searchtri,
                                     struct osub *splitseg,
                                     int segmentflaws, int triflaws)
```

The `insertvertexresult` enum:

```
/* Labels that signify the result of vertex insertion.  The result indicates */
/*   that the vertex was inserted with complete success, was inserted but    */
/*   encroaches upon a subsegment, was not inserted because it lies on a     */
/*   segment, or was not inserted because another vertex occupies the same   */
/*   location.                                                               */

enum insertvertexresult {SUCCESSFULVERTEX, ENCROACHINGVERTEX, VIOLATINGVERTEX,
                         DUPLICATEVERTEX};
```

The `flipstacker` struct:

```
/* A stack of triangles flipped during the most recent vertex insertion.     */
/*   The stack is used to undo the vertex insertion if the vertex encroaches */
/*   upon a subsegment.                                                      */

struct flipstacker {
  triangle flippedtri;                       /* A recently flipped triangle. */
  struct flipstacker *prevflip;               /* Previous flip in the stack. */
};
```

The full context for convenience (the undovertex function the above cast is found):

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                           */
/*  undovertex()   Undo the most recent vertex insertion.                    */
/*                                                                           */
/*  Walks through the list of transformations (flips and a vertex insertion) */
/*  in the reverse of the order in which they were done, and undoes them.    */
/*  The inserted vertex is removed from the triangulation and deallocated.   */
/*  Two triangles (possibly just one) are also deallocated.                  */
/*                                                                           */
/*****************************************************************************/

void undovertex(struct mesh *m, struct behavior *b)   
{
  struct otri fliptri;
  struct otri botleft, botright, topright;
  struct otri botlcasing, botrcasing, toprcasing;
  struct otri gluetri;
  struct osub botlsubseg, botrsubseg, toprsubseg;
  vertex botvertex, rightvertex;
  triangle ptr;                         /* Temporary variable used by sym(). */
  subseg sptr;                      /* Temporary variable used by tspivot(). */

  /* Walk through the list of transformations (flips and a vertex insertion) */
  /*   in the reverse of the order in which they were done, and undo them.   */
  while (m->lastflip != (struct flipstacker *) NULL) {
    /* Find a triangle involved in the last unreversed transformation. */
    decode(m->lastflip->flippedtri, fliptri);

    /* We are reversing one of three transformations:  a trisection of one */
    /*   triangle into three (by inserting a vertex in the triangle), a    */
    /*   bisection of two triangles into four (by inserting a vertex in an */
    /*   edge), or an edge flip.                                           */
    if (m->lastflip->prevflip == (struct flipstacker *) NULL) {
      /* Restore a triangle that was split into three triangles, */
      /*   so it is again one triangle.                          */
      dprev(fliptri, botleft);
      lnextself(botleft);
      onext(fliptri, botright);
      lprevself(botright);
      sym(botleft, botlcasing);
      sym(botright, botrcasing);
      dest(botleft, botvertex);

      setapex(fliptri, botvertex);
      lnextself(fliptri);
      bond(fliptri, botlcasing);
      tspivot(botleft, botlsubseg);
      tsbond(fliptri, botlsubseg);
      lnextself(fliptri);
      bond(fliptri, botrcasing);
      tspivot(botright, botrsubseg);
      tsbond(fliptri, botrsubseg);

      /* Delete the two spliced-out triangles. */
      triangledealloc(m, botleft.tri);
      triangledealloc(m, botright.tri);
    } else if (m->lastflip->prevflip == (struct flipstacker *) &insertvertex) {
      /* Restore two triangles that were split into four triangles, */
      /*   so they are again two triangles.                         */
      lprev(fliptri, gluetri);
      sym(gluetri, botright);
      lnextself(botright);
      sym(botright, botrcasing);
      dest(botright, rightvertex);

      setorg(fliptri, rightvertex);
      bond(gluetri, botrcasing);
      tspivot(botright, botrsubseg);
      tsbond(gluetri, botrsubseg);

      /* Delete the spliced-out triangle. */
      triangledealloc(m, botright.tri);

      sym(fliptri, gluetri);
      if (gluetri.tri != m->dummytri) {
        lnextself(gluetri);
        dnext(gluetri, topright);
        sym(topright, toprcasing);

        setorg(gluetri, rightvertex);
        bond(gluetri, toprcasing);
        tspivot(topright, toprsubseg);
        tsbond(gluetri, toprsubseg);

        /* Delete the spliced-out triangle. */
        triangledealloc(m, topright.tri);
      }

      /* This is the end of the list, sneakily encoded. */
      m->lastflip->prevflip = (struct flipstacker *) NULL;
    } else {
      /* Undo an edge flip. */
      unflip(m, b, &fliptri);
    }

    /* Go on and process the next transformation. */
    m->lastflip = m->lastflip->prevflip;
  }
}
```

My question is, what does such cast try to accomplish and why would be this even possible?

Comment: `Casting a function pointer to a struct pointer? This is some dark magic I don't know about`  The compiler also doesn't know about this "dark magic" either.    Instead of musing over this (IMO poorly written) code, what is the intention of the line that gives the error?  We can see the casting, but the question is what, on a high-level, is that line supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now that cast indeed doesn't make any sense.

But after browsing through the code a little, I found this :

```
if (m->checkquality) {
  poolrestart(&m->flipstackers);
  m->lastflip = (struct flipstacker *) poolalloc(&m->flipstackers);
  m->lastflip->flippedtri = encode(horiz);
  printf("Fatal Error: Contact piyush\n");
  exit(1);
  /* 
  m->lastflip->prevflip = (struct flipstacker *) &insertvertex; 
  */
}
```

Notice that there's the same strange cast, but this time it's an assignment.

So there are two possibilities:

- Either at some point in time `insertvertex` was not a function but an object that could actually be cast to `(struct flipstacker *)`,
- Or the author used the address of `insertvertex` as a magic value, knowing that no valid `flipstacker` object could be at the same address as the `insertvertex` function, and the author's compiler somehow never complained.

Either way, this is a terrible practice, and since it appears that this condition is essentially dead code now that the magic assignment is commented out, I'd recommend filling a bug report and simply removing it in the meantime.

Comment: Thank You. It really doesn't make any sense (the official doc says it was tested with gcc-4.1) and i'm afraid to change this simply because i have no idea what is this supposed to check, really. What do You suggest to change it to?

Comment: You should be able to just remove that whole `else if` block. As far as I know, `&insertvertex` isn't used anywhere else. But really I wouldn't want to use any library that has this kind of code in it. Isn't there an alternative library ?

Comment: Well, that is the problem: the only alternative i know of for the Not-constrained Delaunay is the CGAL (which is simply too big for the project that has 500 lines of code, also doesn't support static libs for the MVC compiler) or the original Triangle.h...but that would require me to write a wrapper myself